How to remove jittery mouse input Unity3D?
I made a first-person camera script and it’s currently attached to the main camera which is a child of my player.
I think I made a mistake with how I made my code which I can’t solve. My mouse sensitivity is set very low, to 2f which is already a decent speed, something like 10f would be uncontrollable.
If I add * Time.deltaTime to: float rotationSpeed = inputVector.x * mouseSensitivity; then my vertical rotation becomes much faster than my horizontal rotation which becomes much slower. If I add * Time.deltaTime to my mouseX and mouseY floats inside Update(), vertical mouse input/rotation no longer works and only horizontal mouse input works. But with that second approach, if I increase mouse sensitivity, horizontal input would work still, but vertical input would go from not working to being extremely jittery. Am I missing something?
using UnityEngine;
public class FollowPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Camera rotation variables
    public float mouseSensitivity = 2f;
    public float topAngleLimit = 80.0f;
    public float bottomAngleLimit = -45.0f;
    private Vector2 inputVector;
    public float cameraPitch = 0.0f;

    public Transform mainCamera;

    //public float horizontalRecoilOffset = 0f;
    public Transform playerBody; // i put the main parent object into this inspector slot

    [SerializeField] private WeaponManager weaponManager; 
    public Aiming aim;

    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;      
    }

    void Update()
    {

        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * nouseSensitivity;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * nouseSensitivity;

        inputVector = new Vector2(mouseX, mouseY);

        CameraRotation(); 
    }

    private void CameraRotation()
    {
        // Adjust vertical/pitch
            cameraPitch -= inputVector.y;
            cameraPitch = ClampAngle(cameraPitch, bottomAngleLimit, topAngleLimit);

            // apply vertical rotation to the camera
            mainCamera.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(cameraPitch, horizontalRecoilOffset, 0.0f);

            // Rotate the player body for horizontal move/yaw
            float rotationSpeed = inputVector.x;
            playerBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * rotationSpeed);
    }

    public static float ClampAngle(float angle, float min, float max)
    {
        if (angle < -360f) angle += 360f;
        if (angle > 360f) angle -= 360f;
        return Mathf.Clamp(angle, min, max);
    }
}


what about using a Vector2 for the mouse sensitivity so you can adjust X and Y individually?

one reason for jitter might also be the rotationThreshold .. why not take any rotation into account even if very small / slow?

also in CameraRotation you do float rotationSpeed = inputVector.x * mouseSensitivity; .. you already applied the sensitivity to the inputVector itself so this is redundant

Yeah you're right, I took out the other 'mouseSensitivity' since it wasn't needed, thanks for pointing that out. I'm going to give your first comment a try so adjust both individually with a Vector2, I will see how that goes. But I think the issue might also be with how I use currentMouseSensitivity? I know not much can be helped with that since the other scripts are not included in this post. But I change sensitivity dynamically for each gun when scoping/aiming/zooming in with them. Will still try the other ideas you gave

I completely removed: if (inputVector.sqrMagnitude >= rotationThreshold) (updated my post) so now the issue seems to be gone, but I still need to test more since I've had no luck so far, not sure why I overlooked that line though

@derHugo do you know why horizontal input is not affected by mousesensitivity at all? For example changing 2f to '0.1f will make vertical mouse input extremely slow, but horizontal will still be very fast. I changed my CameraRotation() twice slightly with no results (minor changes like replacing rotationSpeed)

you still have the mousesensitivity redundancy on cameraPitch -= inputVector.y * mouseSensitivity; as well

My bad I forgot to edit it out of the post but I did now. Still can't seem to solve the horizontal rotation/input speed not being reduced by mouseSensitivity. Even getting rid of all references to currentMouseSensitivity and just using the flat mouseSensitivity does nothing. I have no other code to do with my camera so it's weird

Also removing horizontalRecoilOffset (which I need) from my cam.localRot = Quaternion.Euler() and replacing it with 0.0f does not solve the problem

Let's break down what your code does
Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") returns relatively small values (in pixels moved since the last frame)
you are multiplying this number by the sensitivity:
float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * currentMouseSensitivity
then storing it into the inputVector
inputVector = new Vector2(mouseX, mouseY);
then you are multiplying the Y value again when you're calculating the cameraPitch
cameraPitch -= inputVector.y * mouseSensitivity;
Check if the problem lies in the logic above

You can smooth the input over time for slightly less precision but less jitter. Using Cinemachine will do that automatically for you. Just have an empty gameobject that takes the actual mouse movements and a virtual camera with smooth follow.

I can't use cinemachine because there's 0 resources or information out there on how to use it.

That's not true. There's hundreds of videos on YouTube alone. CodeMonkey usually has good ones, here's his on Cinemachine: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ml8ptNeezsU

That video is 4 years old though and doesn't apply now especially with version 3.1.2+ since all the settings etc are in completely different places. Also my code that I posted was originally cinemachine but I converted it to a standard camera. But it doesn't offer anything for my current question since I'm not using cinemachine
